# In how many ways can a 6-card hand containing 4 kings and 2 queens be dealt from a deck of 52 cards?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In how many ways can a 6-card hand containing 4 kings and 2 queens be dealt from a deck of 52 cards?

I have no clue... 
6 slots, 4! ways of choosing a king and 4P2 ways of choosing a queen. I'm confused. The answer at the end of the book says 6.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. The interpretation used in the answer is that we are counting the number of **hands**. The Kings are determined, and there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose the Queens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes to choosing $2$ queens out of $4$. There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well, each of these hands has all four of the kings and 2 of the four queens.  There are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to choose these two queens, so there are $6$ possible hands.